# Conditionally Sum the first two rows of each group

Tags: r

I have a data frame where I want to sum the top 2 rows of each group, but if one of those 2 entries are a zero to replace it with the next lowest non-zero value.    Also, if there's no other non-zero value to just make the sum=0.  I cannot sort, so that's not an option.

What I have...

```
ID | Prod1 
---|------
A  | 2
A  | 5
A  | 9
B  | 3
B  | 0
B  | 0
B  | 8
B  | 10
C  | 0
C  | 12
C  | 0
C  | 0
```

What I want...

```
ID | Prod1 
---|------
A  | 7
B  | 11
C  | 0
```

**DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    Prod1 = c(2L, 5L, 9L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 10L, 0L, 12L, 0L, 0L
    )), .Names = c("ID", "Prod1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R method using `aggregate`.

```
dfAgg <- aggregate(Prod1~ID, data=df, function(i) sum(i[i != 0][1:2]))
```

Here, sum is fed the first two non-zero elements with `i[i != 0][1:2]`. The first `[` subsets i to elements that are non-zero (defined by `i != 0`), then second `[` takes the first two such elements (defined by `1:2`).

`function(i)`, when used in this manner is called an anonymous function (which python and functional programming refer to as a lambda function). This is a function that that we will use in passing and don't want to give it a name. If all elements are 0, then `sum` returns NA. This line returns

```
dfAgg
  ID Prod1
1  A     7
2  B    11
3  C    NA
```

Now, fill in NAs

```
dfAgg$Prod1[is.na(dfAgg$Prod1)] <- 0

dfAgg
  ID Prod1
1  A     7
2  B    11
3  C     0
```

Comment: Nice. I didnt think that way would satisfy all the conditions and I was getting 12 for group C whenntrying to do it this way hence the "dirty" function I wrote :)

Comment: Yeah. I tried using na.rm=TRUE in `sum` and also got 12 in the final output. I guess that means R replaces the NA in i[!=0][1:2] in the c group with 0 instead of the NA that is is generated by default.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much.  I'm getting more familiar with the aggregate function, but what exactly does it mean in the code for (function(i) sum(i[i!=0][1:2])? From what I've seen the function(i) is just saying you're about to give a function with i being your variable.  I just don't comprehend logically what the code is saying for sum(i[i!=0][1:2]).  I understand i!=0 means i not equal to zero.  Also, if I just wanted the sum of two entries in a row would the function say sum(i[1:2])? Sorry for the long comment just trying to further my comprehension.

Comment: @user3827129 I'll update my answer with some details.